# Listview image click, Display detail at next screen with same Image in C# (wp8.1)

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have made a custom list view with code binding, in my windows phone 8.1 application. 
There is list of images in Listview.

[image: Images displaying in Listview]

My Code is here,

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
      {
    List<product> abc = new List<product>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        helloyouthere();


        //arsal is listview name.

        arsal.DataContext = abc;

        arsal.SelectionChanged += arsal_SelectionChanged;

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    public void helloyouthere()
    {
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/21.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/22.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/23.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/24.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/25.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/26.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/27.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/28.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/29.png" });
        abc.Add(new product() { imagepath = "/Assets/30.png" });

    }

    private async void arsal_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            MessageDialog msgbox2 = new MessageDialog(arsal.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            await msgbox2.ShowAsync();
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(detail), arsal.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

I just want to tap this and want to get full image at next screen,

```
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(detail), arsal.SelectedIndex);
```

My detail page has one image control in xaml file, 
detail.cs page code is here.

```
         public detail()
        {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainPage obj = new MainPage();

       // "imaged"  is my image Control

      // How to get Image here  
    }
```

I wanna display my image here.

not able to get image here.

My About Page Xaml code is here

```
   <Grid x:Name="maingrid">
    <Image x:Name="imaged" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         Width="360" Height="360" Stretch="UniformToFill"   >

    </Image>


</Grid>
```

I'm not getting my image source dynamically at about.cs.  I'm giving exact code, I have tried specific static source in about.cs file,, But every time imaged.source  NULL   and exception display.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you need to write your imagepath as "ms-appx:///Assets/30.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(detail), ((product)arsal.SelectedItem).imagepath)
```

to navigate to your details page.

And then in your details page you have the `OnNavigatedTo` method which you can use to display your image:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var imagePath = e.Parameter as string;

        // Set to image control ImageSource
        imaged.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: Imaged.source every time shows  Null    an exception display at there?

Comment: All the time getting exception...  No source property working for a static path also...     Just     imaged.source    display NULL   in Log.      System.UriFormatException' occurred

Comment: Try to add the UriKind parameter to the Uri constructor, as in my last edit.

Comment: Also Done with this.  But   image source always comes Null,,, There may be another problem.   I have tried this with direct path to image but not to do so,,,  every time exception.

Comment: Could you pleas update your question and add xaml and code of details page, so I can see where the problem is?

Comment: I have added About.xaml  code in my question. would you please check where is the error